# IF Statement - Creating New Column Based on Two Columns

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new column that contains the past values of `df2.past_values` and the future values of `df2.future_value` called `df2['past_future_mix']`.

If window = 0, these are past values, window = 1, these are future values

I am trying to use a if elif statement, however i get this error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

# Set up input data (taken from original post)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'past_value': [100, 200, 200, 300, 350, 400, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
    'future_value': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 800, 900, 900, 950, 975, 1000],
    'window': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'category': ['Category A']*4 + ['Category B']*4 + ['Category C']*4})

ca_list = df1.category.unique()

bigdf = pd.DataFrame()

for cat in cat_list:
    df2 = df1[(df1.category == cat)]
    if df2['window'] == 0:
        df2['past_future_mix'] = df2['past_value']
    elif df2['window'] == 1:
        df2['past_future_mix'] = df2['future_value']
    bigdf = bigdf.append(df2)
```

This is the error message that i am getting:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-cfdd200ce9ff> in <module>
     16 for cat in cat_list:
     17     df2 = df1[(df1.category == cat)]
---> 18     if df2['window'] == 0:
     19         df2['past_future_mix'] = df2['past_value']
     20     elif df2['window'] == 1:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1553             "The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1554             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".format(
-> 1555                 self.__class__.__name__
   1556             )
   1557         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I changed `if df2['window] == 0` to `if 0 in df2['window']`, however it does not print a dataframe now.

```
for cat in cat_list:
    df2 = df1[(df1.category == cat)]
    if 0 in df2['window']:
        df2['past_future_mix'] = df2['past_value']
    elif 1 in df2['window']:
        df2['past_future_mix'] = df2['future_value']
    bigdf = bigdf.append(df2)

print(bigdf)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: @AMC, Im not sure, im not using | or & operators.

Comment: The issue wouldn’t be caused by either of those operators anyway, much to the contrary.

Comment: @AMC, enlighten me

Comment: Please share the entire error message. I have an idea of where the issue is, but I can’t be certain.

Comment: @AMC, added to post, thank you

Comment: Yup, it’s indeed the if statements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.loc`

```
for cat in cat_list:
    df2 = df1[(df1.category == cat)]
    df2.loc[df2['window'] == 0,  'past_future_mix'] = df2['past_value']
    df2.loc[df2['window'] == 1,  'past_future_mix'] = df2['future_value']
    bigdf = bigdf.append(df2)
```

Comment: This prints an empty dataframe also.

Comment: you defined `ca_list = df1.category.unique()` but called `for cat in cat_list:`